# RocksDB iterator seek until last matching prefix

Tags: clojure, prefix, seek, rocksdb, rocksdb-java

How do I tell a RocksDB iterator to seek until the last matching prefix?

In Clojure using the RocksDB Java API:

```
(import '(org.rocksdb RocksDB Options ReadOptions RocksIterator Slice))
(let [opts (-> (ReadOptions.)
               (.setPrefixSameAsStart true)
               (.setTotalOrderSeek true))
      iter (.newIterator db)]
  (.seek iter (.getBytes ("some-prefix:"))
  (.key iter))
=> "not-matching-prefix"
```

Do I have to manually check if the next key matches the prefix? This seems suboptimal because I have to stream in the whole key to check it, when RocksDB could eject early.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can provide RocksDB the upper bound to optimize it - by using `setIterateUpperBound` in `ReadOptions`.